# Reset custom form elements (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, forms

I'd like to reset multiple textareas and input files by specifying them manually, how do I do with jQuery.

I used this to clear forms until now:

```
$('.clear').click(function () {
        $('form#input')[0].reset();
    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "specifying them manually" means?

Comment: do u want to clear textarea content?

Comment: So something like `$('textarea#one', 'textarea#two').reset();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set all of the values of the textareas and inputs on the form to empty:

```
  $('.clear').click(function() {

       $('form textarea,form input').val('');
  });
```